In RISCV, is Each thread has a own PC value in multithreading Program?
Im currently working on a Hard ware for Data Race detect
So I track each instructions and made history table for race detect.
I made C program for Intended data race and Track instructions by PC value
but regardless of data race I cant track multi thread.
So my question is "Is Each thread has a own PC value in multithreading Program?"
for eg
if thread A and B attempt to use
**"108ac: 8141a783 lw a5,-2028(gp) # 1209c / "
**
at the same time
is PC value is different?
l mean
A's PC=108ac
B's PC =108ab
like this
Disassembling the test program to check the PC value and create and debug the hardware history table based on it, but each thread is executed sequentially and no specific command is sandwiched between the threads (even though a data race has occurred)

Each thread of execution needs its own PC, which is changed by the OS kernel when it preempts the current thread to switch in a new. Otherwise threads (or processes) would not be possible. With that said, there's usually only one PC register, and swapped out threads have their current PC stored somewhere else.

Every thread has its own architectural state (registers, including program counter).  If multiple threads are running the same functions, especially the same loop, it's possible that both their PCs point to the same instruction.  Just like in C how it's possible to have int *p = &foo, *q = &foo; with two pointers that happen to point to the same place but you can point one somewhere else without affecting the other.

It's not really clear what you what to know. Obviously PC would be separate and generally different for each thread in multithreaded program. However, you seem to be asking if PC can be different for different threads executing the same instruction? If that, then no PC would be the same. Same instruction, same PC (in fact, your example of PC==108ab is impossible on risc-v - unless you are looking at some internal CPU state mid-execution, and even then I doubt such a value can be seen anywhere).

Yes, each thread has its own Program Counter (PC) value in a multithreading program.
Each thread can execute independently and maintain its own PC value, which allows it to keep track of its execution state separately from other threads.
